# Get value from a dictionary into a JSON file

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I need to get all the `bodyHtml` and `authorId` values from the file that appears here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10EGOAWsw3G5-ETUryYX7__JPOfNwUsL6/view?usp=sharing

I have tried several ways, but I always find the error of: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

I've tried several ways, this is my last code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import requests
import datetime

data = json.loads(open('file.json').read())

coments = data['headDocument']['content']['id']

for comment in data['headDocument']['content']['content']['bodyHtml']:
    info = comment
print(info)
```

and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coments.py", line 16, in <module>
    for comment in data['headDocument']['content']['content']['bodyHtml']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your headDocument['content'] is a list, so you should loop through it. Like this:

```
for item in data['headDocument']['content']:
    print(item['content']['bodyHtml'])
```

Comment: Some of the objects do not have the `item['content']['bodyHtml']` key, your script will return an error for that. So you will need to use a try/except statement to catch an exception for keys that might not be there.